# Select all judges that had their verdict changed at least half of the times

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
case(caseId,judge,verdict)

appeal(caseId,verdict)
```

And I want to select all judges that had their verdict changed at least half of the times (for example, if a judge presided in 5 cases and 3 of his verdicts were changed in the appeal, I want to select him).

I tried to solve it using nested queries but I got confused because I don't really understand how to refer to the outer query from the nested query.

**Update:** What I've tried (I don't really know how to get the nested query to only select judges which are the same judges as the outer query)

```
SELECT DISTINCT judge
FROM case c
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C WHERE c.judge = case.judge) <= 2 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appeal,case WHERE case.cid = appeal.cid AND case.verdict <> appeal.verdict)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Im using paper :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from (
   select c.caseid,
          c.verdict,
          c.judge,
          count(*) over (partition by c.judge) as total_cases_per_judge,
          sum(
             case
               when (c.verdict <> coalesce(a.verdict, -1)) then 1
               else 0
             end) over (partition by c.judge) as changed_cases
   from "case" as c
     left join appeal a on a.caseid = c.caseid
) t
where changed_cases >= total_cases_per_judge/2;
```

`case` is a reserved keyword, you should not use it as a table name (and that's why I had to put it into double quotes, otherwise reserved words are not allowed as identifiers)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try something like:

```
SELECT n.judge FROM (
    SELECT s.judge, COUNT(*) AS total, COUNT(s.changed_verdict) AS changed FROM (
        SELECT c.caseId, c.judge, c.verdict, a.verdict AS changed_verdict FROM case c
            LEFT JOIN appeal a ON a.caseId = c.caseId AND a.verdict != c.verdict
    ) s
    GROUP BY s.judge
) n WHERE n.changed >= n.total / 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this should be fine:

```
SELECT cases.judge, SUM(appeal.verdict != cases.verdict) / COUNT(*) AS changed
FROM cases
JOIN appeal ON appeal.case_id = cases.case_id
GROUP BY cases.judge
HAVING changed > 0.5
```

I just renamed `case` to `cases` to not bother with identifier escaping.